# How to repair a hole in exterior concrete foundation

Tags: repair, concrete, hole

We have had this hole in our exterior foundation for a few years. The way we discovered it was that water was leaking into our basement finished room, and when I looked outside, I discovered this hole in a corner where the porch foundation and the house foundation meet. It is now the size of a peach. We have dealt with it temporarily by covering the whole area with tarp and duct tape, and have never had any water in the basement since then.

My question is, how do we repair a hole that is empty behind it? There is some sort of crawl space underneath the porch (porch is concrete). Here is a picture of the hole:

[image]

We are somewhat novices at DIY - I can build furniture fairly easily, but concrete is something new to me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any idea how deep this hole is? Is it actually in the foundation or down in dirt.

Comment: This hole leads into a crawl space underneath the porch which is maybe about 2 feet deep. The foundation to the on the left side of the picture supports that porch, if that makes sense.

Comment: The hole is in the foundation. We get a lot of rainfall that overwhelms our gutters at times and it pounds down right around this area. My theory is that the water wore away the concrete in this area, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Can you actually crawl into the crawl space from the other side of the porch? or is it just a void in the concrete that should have been filled when they pored the porch.

Comment: It is a void under the porch - there is no way to access this space. The only reason I called it a crawlspace was because that's kind of what it looks like. It's about 2 feet deep and there is gravel on the bottom. I was surprised to see it there when we first discovered the hole because the porch is a concrete slab. At first I thought maybe it pulled away, but the distance between the gravel and porch slab is so great and generally even that it doesn't seem to be accidental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clean up that area and fill it up with gravel. Compact it the best you can shoving the gravel down and to the back. When you're a few inches from the hole pour in cement. Pour in enough so it's a few inches above the hole and then slope it down away from the hole to deflect water from there. Fixing the gutter problem, maybe adding another downspout, should be done too. Good luck

Comment: Thank you! We have thought about adding another downspout and increasing the size to a 6 inch vs. a 4 inch.